# Does this converge at the point zero.

Tags: limits

The problem:

Given the series $u_n=e^{nx}-e^{(n+1)x}$  find $\sum_{n=1}^N u_n$ in terms of n and x.

Find the set of values which the infinite series converges, and give the sum to infinity.

I did the limit test, and I am stuck at how to find the limit at x=0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sum telescopes, giving partial sums
$$s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N u_n=(e^x-e^{2x})+(e^{2x}-e^{3x})+\ldots+(e^{Nx}-e^{(N+1)x})=e^x-e^{(N+1)x}.$$
If $x<0$, then $s_N\to e^x$ as $N\to\infty$.

If $x=0$, then $s_N=0$ identically for all $N$, so $s_N\to 0$.

If $x>0$, then the sum diverges.

Comment: so why don't you say it converges for $ x \le 0$ ? Doesn't the properties of $e^x$ contain 1 & 2?  Why do you have a separate case for $x = 0$?

Comment: Because $e^0=1$

Comment: so it converges when x=0, just making sure I fully understand the usages of the word convergence.

Comment: That's correct, the series converges for $x\le 0$.